# Differentiating $f(r,\theta)=(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)$ with limits verification

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Differentiate $f(r,\theta)=(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)$. I was taught that differentiation should be of the next form:

1. Checking differentiability.
2. Calculating the differential.

For a very long time I practice that, studied it and then took this course again, really struggling with the different tools related to differentiation, derivative, partial derivative, matrix of derivatives, vector of derivative, and what I am really expected to find, I sometimes can't tell. I guess I am to arrive at a map or a matrix like $\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta &-r \sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & r\cos\theta \end{bmatrix}$, but I don't see how it satisfies the limit definition. I just get various expressions leading nowhere, and I could use your help understanding how such an expression constitutes the differential by definition.

Comment: Yes, you should arrive at a matrix, the Jacobian matrix: $\begin{bmatrix} \partial_r f_1 & \partial_\theta f_1 \\ \partial_r f_2 & \partial_\theta f_2\end{bmatrix}$. Which is the one you wrote down. That's it.

Comment: I am not sure it provides me with a genuine understanding of the area...The whole syllabus relies upon Analysis...

Comment: What you need is understanding the reason why the differential is represented by the Jacobian matrix. [This site](http://mathinsight.org/) could help you. (See [here](http://mathinsight.org/derivative_matrix)).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it all depends on what definition you use for the definition of the derivative. The book that I use (Advanced Calculus of Several Variables, Edwards) for the course (real analysis) has this theorem:

The mapping $F:D \to \mathbb R^m$ for $D \subset \mathbb R^n$ is differentiable at $\mathbf a \in D$ if there exists a linear mapping $L:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ such that
$$\lim_{\mathbf h \to \mathbf 0}\frac{F(\mathbf a + \mathbf h)-F(\mathbf a) - L(\mathbf h)}{|\mathbf h|} = \mathbf 0$$

If this is true, then $L$ is noted as the differential of $F$, $dF_{\mathbf a}(\mathbf x)$ where
$$dF_{\mathbf a}(\mathbf x) = F'(\mathbf a)\mathbf x$$
under matrix multiplication for all $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n$

Using that, we can create another definition of differentiability:

If $F:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is differentiable at $\mathbf a$, then the directional derivative $D_{\mathbf v}F(\mathbf a)$ along $\mathbf v$ exists for all $\mathbf v \in \mathbb R^n$ and
$$D_{\mathbf v}F(\mathbf a)=dF_{\mathbf a}(\mathbf x)$$

Proving this is simple; just substitute $\mathbf h = t\mathbf v$ into the earlier equation and let $t \to 0$. Note that
$$D_{\mathbf v}F(\mathbf a)=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{F(\mathbf a + t\mathbf v)-F(\mathbf a)}{t}$$

Of course, we can do more with this. Taking that definition of the directional derivative, we can say that if $F:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is differentiable at $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf v = (v_1,...,v_n)$ then:

$$D_{\mathbf v}F(\mathbf a) = \sum_{j=1}^nv_jD_jF(\mathbf a)$$

Additionally, we can say that a function $F:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is differentiable at $\mathbf a$ if and only if each of its component functions is, and that

$$dF_{\mathbf a} = \left(dF_{\mathbf a}^1,...,dF_{\mathbf a}^m\right)$$

where the superscript denotes which component function. Furthermore

$$F'(\mathbf a)=D_jF^i(\mathbf a)$$

Which is the derivative along the j'th variable of the i'th composite function of F. So, when you use the earlier equation for the differential, it becomes clear that you're just taking the derivative in respect to each variable. This, by the way, is the Jacobian. This can be proved with what we already have:

$$dF_{\mathbf a}(\mathbf v) = \left(dF_{\mathbf a}^1(\mathbf v),...,dF_{\mathbf a}^m(\mathbf v)\right)^T$$

Note that these all should be transposed, but I cannot figure out a nice way of typing that out That's what the $T$ is for.

$$= \left(\sum_{j=1}^nD_jF(\mathbf a)^1v_j,...,\sum_{j=1}^nD_jF(\mathbf a)^mv_j\right)^T$$

$$=(D_jF^i(\mathbf a))(v_1,...,v_m)^T$$

Using all this, we can then say that if $F:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is continuously differentiable at $\mathbf a$, then it is differentiable at $\mathbf a$. A function is continuously differentiable at a point should all the partial derivatives exist at that point, and the function be continuous at that point. I'll not write the proof for the sake of brevity.

I hope that helps with your understanding of this material.